# Schmidt decomposition of density matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, vectors, density-operator, open-quantum-systems

For a bipartite system:
$\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_{a}\otimes\mathcal{H}_{b}$ described by a density operator $\hat{\rho}_{ab}$, I can promote it to a vector in the Liouville space, $|\hat{\rho}_{ab}\rangle\rangle$. The Schmidt decomposition for such a vector would be:
$$
|\hat{\rho}_{ab}\rangle\rangle=\sum_{n}\gamma_{n}|\hat{\sigma}_{n}\rangle\rangle\otimes|\hat{\tau}_{n}\rangle\rangle
$$
where $\{|\hat{\sigma}_{n}\rangle\rangle\}$ and $\{|\hat{\tau}_{n}\rangle\rangle\}$ will be orthonormal (in terms of the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product) basis of $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{H}_{a})$ and $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{H}_{b})$ respectively. Is there any argument to relate those bases to the physical reduced density matrix for the subsystems A and B?

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of relation you envision? You mean similar as the Schmidt basis is the eigenbasis of the reduced density matrix? You could define a "super-reduced density matrix" (or reduced super-density-matrix?) and make an analogous statement, of course.

Comment: I was thinking that since the linear state vector space, the linear superoperator space and the Liouville space are isomorphic there must be some relationship between the "super-reduced density matrix" and the reduced density matrix acting on the state vector space. However I cannot see the physical differences between them. Could it be possible that the reduced density matrix captures the quantum dynamics of the subsystem state by itself, while the "super-reduced density matrix" captures the dynamics of the same subsystem within a larger framework of the joint system?